# desktop: how to enable sleep from lock screen?

Tags: desktop, power-management, screen-lock

I sometimes find I have just "awoken" (resumed from suspend to memory) my Debian-8-running device only to find I must do something else. At that point I am confronted by my "lock screen" (i.e., the screenlocker's GUI), and I am doubly annoyed:

1. Under current conditions (about which I'm asking), I must first login, then put the device back to sleep (i.e., suspend it to memory). This is because

1.1. my lock screen has no GUI for changing the device's power status

1.2. my device's sleep keychord (Fn+F4) has no effect while at the lock screen (i.e., until I login/unlock)

2. While I am very much a Linux bigot, and quite anti-Windows, I cannot deny that I would not have this problem if using a Windows device, since all that I've used since at least NT (fortunately with decreasing frequency) have allowed one to sleep from the lock screen.

Hence I have the following questions:

1. Is this question desktop-specific or distro-specific or kernel-specific? I'm guessing (b) but ICBW. FWIW,

1.1. I observe this behavior on separate (Debian) devices, one running desktop=Cinnamon, the other running desktop=MATE. Of course both are GNOME-based, so this could indeed be a desktop-specific question.

1.2. The Cinnamon box (as I believe is also the MATE box) is currently running the following:

```
$ lsb_release -ds
LMDE 2 Betsy
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.5
$ uname -rv
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02)
$ gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

2. How to determine which screenlocker I am running, and its version? From the shell (== screen not locked) I see only

   ```
   me@it:~$ ps aux | fgrep -ie 'lock'
   root     56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S&lt;   Jul13   0:00 [kblockd]
   me     5879  0.0  0.0  12732  2088 pts/3    S+   17:43   0:00 grep -F --color=auto -ie lock
   ```
3. Is there already a way to configure the screenlocker (whichever I am running--see question 2) to change the device's power status to allow sleep?
4. If not, on whom should I put a feature request for this? I can understand why one might not want to allow restart or halt/poweroff (and perhaps hibernate) from the lock screen, but I certainly

   - believe that this should be a configurable user preference
   - want the ability to sleep from the lock screen.

Comment: @don_crissti: `desktop` in the sense of Cinnamon or MATE? or `desktop` in the sense of GNOME?

Comment: OK... apparently, you should be [able to use the suspend key](http://superuser.com/q/748482) from the lock screen on any `systemd` setup (this should work irrespective of your DE). If your question is about having a gui option on the lock screen to suspend then no, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @don_crissti: I'll give [that](http://superuser.com/q/748482) a shot, though `systemd` in LMDE2 is currently [only slightly implemented](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2808#comment-116426).

Comment: unfortunately not working for me, though this may be an LMDE2 problem (asking [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=236&t=194829&p=1190054#p1190054))

Comment: <expletives deleted/> locked the thread, so I have reasked [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=238&t=225712)

Comment: I just tried it on my laptop (I'm using archlinux with gnome 3 on a dell xps l502x) and it works OK so clearly something's wrong on your setup.

Comment: @don_crissti: that's what I pointed to [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296387/desktop-how-to-enable-sleep-from-lock-screen?noredirect=1#comment520411_296387). [LMDE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#LMDE_2) includes `logind` but uses `sysvinit`; the transition will probably not complete until [LMDE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#LMDE_3).